# How to purge emacs from LMDE 2

Tags: linux, debian, emacs, debian-jessie

I do not know if it's related only to LMDE 2 or debian jessie in general, but I just saw I had emacs installed so I wanted to remove it, and if I do:

```
sudo apt purge emacs24
```

I get:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  xemacs21-basesupport xemacs21-bin xemacs21-mule xemacs21-mulesupport xemacs21-support
```

I tried purging emacs24 still, in order to then purge xemacs21, but when I do so it reinstalls emacs24.

I am not a VIM user, but it still pisses me off a bit...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have have a package that depends on "[emacsen](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacsen)", which is a "[virtual package](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/virtual-package-names-list.txt)" used to say that a package depends on any version of emacs.

You can check this using the following [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package):

```
apt-cache rdepends emacsen
```

Or if you are familiar with the "aptitude" command, checking the "Packages who depend on emacs24/xemacs21-bin" section.

Comment: I have no `emacsen` package but this led me on the right track. I searched more to list only the installed dependencies, and if I do `aptitude why emacs` it gives me false info, so I tried `apt-cache rdepends --installed emacs` which told me this one was not installed. Tried the same with emacs24 and the culprit was `uim-el`. After purging that, I can delete emacs* just fine. Thanks!